# Running PowerShell script for Exchange 2010 remotely using WMIC

Tags: powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010, wmic

In general I'm trying to create mailbox on Exchange Server 2010 remotely using wmic. I have a following environment setup:

Systems are not in the same domain.
System 1 (from where I execute): running Windows 7 x64 
System 2 (target system with Exchange on board): running Windows Server 2008 R2. There I have PowerShell script called addmailbox.ps1:

```
$secure_pwsd = convertto-securestring TESTPASSWORD -asplaintext -force
New-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName TESTMAILBOX@MYDOMAIN.com -Alias SOMEALIAS -Name SOMENAME -OrganizationalUnit Users -Password $secure_pwsd -FirstName SOMEFIRSTNAME -LastName SOMELASTNAME -DisplayName "LASTNAME FIRSTNAME" -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false
exit
```

If I run the script locally from System 2 it works fine, mailbox created as expected, so I tried to run it remotely from System 1 like this

```
wmic /node:IP /user:DOMAIN\Administrator /password:PASS process call create 'powershell.exe -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; C:\scripts\addmailbox.ps1"'
```

WMIC reported that the remote process created successfully. On System 2 in task manager I can see that the process is running and child PowerShell process also spawned, but both processes are not completed. I suppose PowerShell wait for user input or something. To test, I added the key "-noninteractive" to executing command and catch the following errors

`VERBOSE: Connecting to HOSTNAME
[HOSTNAME] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : A specified logon session does
 not exist. It may already have been terminated. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
Failed to connect to any Exchange Server in the current site.
Read-Host : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\ConnectFunctions.ps1:47 char:18
+         $fqdn=read-host <<<<  -prompt "Please enter the Server FQDN where you want to connect"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Read-Host], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ReadHostCommand`

VERBOSE: Connecting to 
New-PSSession : Cannot bind parameter 'ConnectionUri'. Cannot convert value "http:///powershell?serializationLevel=Full
" to type "System.Uri". Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\ConnectFunctions.ps1:229 char:43
+             $session = new-pssession -connectionURI <<<<  "http://$fqdn/powershell?serializationLevel=Full" -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -SessionOption $so #-erroraction silentlycontinue
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-PSSession], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand

The term 'New-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
 spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\scripts\addmailbox.ps1:3 char:12
+ New-Mailbox <<<<  -UserPrincipalName TESTMAILBOX@MYDOMAIN.com -Alias SOMEALIAS -Name SOMENAME -OrganizationalUnit Users -Password $secure_pwsd -FirstName SOMEFIRSTNAME -LastName SOMELASTNAME -DisplayName "LASTNAME FIRSTNAME" -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-Mailbox:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I repeat that these commands work fine locally on System 2. Direct specification of the FDQN in PS script file doesn't solve the problem. Please, do not suggest to use PsExec instead of WMIC or establish remote connection using PowerShells. Thanks for the advices!